# How to use indirect reference to read contents into a data table in R.

Tags: r, indirect-objects

How do you use indirect references in R? More specifically, in the following simple read statement, I would like to be able to use a variable name to read inputFile into data table myTable.

> myTable <- read.csv(inputFile, sep=",", header=T)

Instead of the above, I want to define

> refToMyTable <- "myTable"

Then, how can I use refToMyTable instead of myTable to read inputFile into myTable?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R doesn't really have references like that, but you can use strings to retrieve/create variables of that name.

But first let me say this is generally **not** a good practice. If you're looking to do this type of thing, it's generally a sign that you're not doing it "the R way.'

Nevertheless

```
assign(refToMyTable, read.csv(inputFile, sep=",", header=T))
```

Should to the trick. And the complement to `assign` is `get` to retrieve a variable's value using it's name.

Comment: This works very well. Thank you very much! Regarding your comment about this not being the R way, you may well be right. This works better for me to pass things back and forth between R and a UI I have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like the following:

```
reftomytable='~/Documents/myfile.csv'
myTable=read.csv(reftomytable)
```

Comment: Your solution is for a reference to file. I want a reference to a data table in the read command.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `assign` as mentioned by MrFlick.

When you want the contents of the object named "myTable" you would use `get`:

```
 get("myTable")
 get(refToMyTable)   # since get will evaluate its argument
```

(It would be better to assign results of multiple such dataframes to a ist object or a Reference Class.)

If you wanted a language-name object you would use `as.name`:

```
as.name("myTable")
 # myTable    .... is printed at the console; note no quotes
str(as.name("myTable"))
 #symbol myTable
```

Comment: In that case, I need to use 
as.name(refToMyTable) <- read.csv(inputFile, sep=",", header=T)
which does not work. as.name() works perhaps to see the content but not to assign content.

Comment: So checkmark the answer that gave you `assign` and people can stop looking at the question as unanswered.